# Why does adjacent sibling selector not work as expected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to highlight ranges of dates in a calendar (monthly view). The ranges of dates should be rounded of at both sides. I can round of the left side, but I cannot get the right side to work. What's the problem here?

```css
/* For the first highlighted li element in any range (this works well) */
.days li:not(.highlighted) + li.highlighted {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

/* For the last highlighted li element in any range (this doesn't work) */
.days li.highlighted + li:not(.highlighted) {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
    <ul class="weeks">
      <li>Sun</li>
      <li>Mon</li>
      <li>Tue</li>
      <li>Wed</li>
      <li>Thu</li>
      <li>Fri</li>
      <li>Sat</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="days">
      <li class="inactive">26</li>
      <li class="inactive">27</li>
      <li class="inactive">28</li>
      <li class="inactive">29</li>
      <li class="inactive">30</li>
      <li class="inactive">31</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li class="highlighted">2</li>
      <li class="highlighted">3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've provided [the full HTML code and an example in a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prtLhb6w/8/) as well.
And here is the full code :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #9B59B6;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.calendar {
  padding: 20px;
}

.calendar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.calendar .days {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.calendar li {
  color: #333;
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  font-size: 1.07rem;
}

.calendar .weeks li {
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: default;
}

.calendar .days li {
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.days li.highlighted {
  background-color: lightblue;
}


/* For the first highlighted li element in any range */

.days li:not(.highlighted)+li.highlighted {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}


/* For the last highlighted li element in any range */

.days li.highlighted+li:not(.highlighted) {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="calendar">
    <ul class="weeks">
      <li>Sun</li>
      <li>Mon</li>
      <li>Tue</li>
      <li>Wed</li>
      <li>Thu</li>
      <li>Fri</li>
      <li>Sat</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="days">
      <li class="inactive">26</li>
      <li class="inactive">27</li>
      <li class="inactive">28</li>
      <li class="inactive">29</li>
      <li class="inactive">30</li>
      <li class="inactive">31</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li class="highlighted">3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>13</li>
      <li>14</li>
      <li>15</li>
      <li>16</li>
      <li>17</li>
      <li>18</li>
      <li class="highlighted">19</li>
      <li class="highlighted">20</li>
      <li class="active highlighted">21</li>
      <li class="highlighted">22</li>
      <li class="highlighted">23</li>
      <li class="highlighted">24</li>
      <li class="highlighted">25</li>
      <li class="highlighted">26</li>
      <li class="highlighted">27</li>
      <li class="highlighted">28</li>
      <li class="highlighted">29</li>
      <li class="highlighted">30</li>
      <li class="inactive highlighted">1</li>
      <li class="inactive highlighted">2</li>
      <li class="inactive highlighted">3</li>
      <li class="inactive">4</li>
      <li class="inactive">5</li>
      <li class="inactive">6</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Debugging questions need to be self-contained; a link to a JSFiddle _as well_ is fine, but not at the expense of the code in your question being incomplete. Please edit your question to include a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue it that with `.days li.highlighted + li:not(.highlighted)` you are selecting the element after the last `.highlighted` and that one doesn't have the lightblue background so no round border can be displayed.

As shown by [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76073522/1811992), there is **no reliable CSS selector to target the last element with a specific class**. And the safest would be to add a class to the last elements with the `.highlighted` class.

If you cannot do that, you could use a workaround with a pseudo element to make the last round border :

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #9B59B6;
}
.wrapper{
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

.calendar{
  padding: 20px;
}
.calendar ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.calendar .days{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.calendar li{
  color: #333;
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  font-size: 1.07rem;
}
.calendar .weeks li{
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: default;
}
.calendar .days li{
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.days li.highlighted{
  background-color: lightblue;
}

/* For the first highlighted li element in any range */
.days li:not(.highlighted) + li.highlighted {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

/* For the last highlighted li element in any range */

li.highlighted {
  position: relative;
}
li.highlighted::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="calendar">
    <ul class="weeks">
      <li>Sun</li>
      <li>Mon</li>
      <li>Tue</li>
      <li>Wed</li>
      <li>Thu</li>
      <li>Fri</li>
      <li>Sat</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="days">
      <li class="inactive">26</li>
      <li class="inactive">27</li>
      <li class="inactive">28</li>
      <li class="inactive">29</li>
      <li class="inactive">30</li>
      <li class="inactive">31</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li class="highlighted">3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>13</li>
      <li>14</li>
      <li>15</li>
      <li>16</li>
      <li>17</li>
      <li>18</li>
      <li class="highlighted">19</li>
      <li class="highlighted">20</li>
      <li class="active highlighted">21</li>
      <li class="highlighted">22</li>
      <li class="highlighted">23</li>
      <li class="highlighted">24</li>
      <li class="highlighted">25</li>
      <li class="highlighted">26</li>
      <li class="highlighted">27</li>
      <li class="highlighted">28</li>
      <li class="highlighted">29</li>
      <li class="highlighted">30</li>
      <li class="inactive highlighted">1</li>
      <li class="inactive highlighted">2</li>
      <li class="inactive highlighted">3</li>
      <li class="inactive">4</li>
      <li class="inactive">5</li>
      <li class="inactive">6</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that :

- the pseudo element is applied to all the elements with the `.highlighted` class. but it can only be seen over the first elements after the `.highlighted` ones
- I added `overflow: hidden;` on the `.days` element to hide the pseudo elements that shouldn't be seen (at the end of each line)

Answer (score 2):

This is a live demo of your code:

```css
li.highlighted {
  background: #aaf;
}

.days li:not(.highlighted)+li.highlighted {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.days li.highlighted+li:not(.highlighted) {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class=days>
  <li>1</li>
  <li class=highlighted>2</li>
  <li class=highlighted>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

You're targetting `li:not(.highlighted)` but since it has no visible border or background colour you can't see any difference.

When I set a background on the other li elements you can see the radius on *4*:

```css
li {
  background: #afa;
}

li.highlighted {
  background: #aaf;
}

.days li:not(.highlighted)+li.highlighted {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.days li.highlighted+li:not(.highlighted) {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class=days>
  <li>1</li>
  <li class=highlighted>2</li>
  <li class=highlighted>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

You want to target `li.highlighted`, but that isn't the subject of the selector.

The [`:has()` psuedo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) will let you make the highlighted li element the subject **but browser support is still lacking** (most major browsers support it now, but Firefox's implementation is still buggy and locked behind a feature flag).

```css
li {
  background: #afa;
}

li.highlighted {
  background: #aaf;
}

.days li:not(.highlighted)+li.highlighted {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.days li.highlighted:has(+ li:not(.highlighted)) {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class=days>
  <li>1</li>
  <li class=highlighted>2</li>
  <li class=highlighted>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

You're be safest adding an extra class:

```css
li {
  background: #afa;
}

li.highlighted {
  background: #aaf;
}

.days li:not(.highlighted)+li.highlighted {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.days li.highlighted.end-of-set {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class=days>
  <li>1</li>
  <li class=highlighted>2</li>
  <li class="highlighted end-of-set">3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option (in addition to the already proposed solutions) is to use `:before` and `:after` in `.days li.highlighted + li:not(.highlighted)` with the colors used:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #9B59B6;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  ;
}

.calendar {
  --background: #fff;
  --highlighted: lightblue;
  --radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: var(--background);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)
}

.calendar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.calendar .days {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.calendar li {
  color: #333;
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  font-size: 1.07rem;
}

.calendar .weeks li {
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: default;
}

.calendar .days li {
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding:0 var(--radius);
}

/* highlighted styles */

.days li.highlighted {
  background-color: var(--highlighted);
}

.days li:not(.highlighted) + li.highlighted {
  border-top-left-radius: var(--radius);
  border-bottom-left-radius: var(--radius);
}

.days li.highlighted + li:not(.highlighted) {
  position: relative;
}

.days li.highlighted + li:not(.highlighted):before,
.days li.highlighted + li:not(.highlighted):after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--radius);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.days li.highlighted + li:not(.highlighted):before{
  background-color: var(--background);
}

.days li.highlighted + li:not(.highlighted):after{
  background-color: var(--highlighted);
  border-radius:0 var(--radius) var(--radius) 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="calendar">
    <ul class="weeks">
      <li>Sun</li>
      <li>Mon</li>
      <li>Tue</li>
      <li>Wed</li>
      <li>Thu</li>
      <li>Fri</li>
      <li>Sat</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="days">
      <li class="inactive">26</li>
      <li class="inactive">27</li>
      <li class="inactive">28</li>
      <li class="inactive">29</li>
      <li class="inactive">30</li>
      <li class="inactive">31</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li class="highlighted">3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>13</li>
      <li>14</li>
      <li>15</li>
      <li>16</li>
      <li>17</li>
      <li>18</li>
      <li class="highlighted">19</li>
      <li class="highlighted">20</li>
      <li class="active highlighted">21</li>
      <li class="highlighted">22</li>
      <li class="highlighted">23</li>
      <li class="highlighted">24</li>
      <li class="highlighted">25</li>
      <li class="highlighted">26</li>
      <li class="highlighted">27</li>
      <li class="highlighted">28</li>
      <li class="highlighted">29</li>
      <li class="highlighted">30</li>
      <li class="inactive highlighted">1</li>
      <li class="inactive highlighted">2</li>
      <li class="inactive highlighted">3</li>
      <li class="inactive">4</li>
      <li class="inactive">5</li>
      <li class="inactive">6</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, the selection will not go beyond the cell, as in @web-tiki solution.